# How to access Input data passed from parent component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have playlist component as a child Component, the parent pass in an input 'playlist' which is an Object of Array.

```
  playList: {
    headerPlaylists: Array<any>,
    bodyPlaylists: Array<any>
  } = {
    headerPlaylists: [],
    bodyPlaylists: []
  }
```

The Child Component as below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'playlist',
  styleUrls: ['app/channel/playlist/playlist.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app/channel/playlist/playlist.html',
  directives: [VideoItemComponent],
  inputs: ['playlist']
})
```

My question is, in my class, how do I get access to the inputs passed in from it's parent component, say, simply console.log(playlist), is there a way to do that?

```
export class PlaylistComponent {

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thierry is correct w.r.t. the availability of inputs across the lifecycle, but how this works is much clearer if you use [`@Input()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html) on the field rather than `inputs` in the metadata.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'playlist',
  styleUrls: ['app/channel/playlist/playlist.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app/channel/playlist/playlist.html',
  directives: [VideoItemComponent],
 // inputs: ['playlist'] // would be redundant
})
class PlaylistComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() playlist: YourPlaylistType; // i.e. the data structure you posted

  ngOnInit(){
     // use this.playlist 
  }
}
```

Note that, largely for this reason, specifying inputs via `@Input()` is preferred over using inputs as per the [ng2 style guide](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-style-guide).

Answer (score 1):

The `playlist` property will be available within the `ngOnInit` hook method of the component:

```
export class PlaylistComponent {
  playlist: any; // or a specify type instead of any

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.playlist); // is null
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.playlist); // is set
  }
}
```

In the constructor, the property isn't set yet.

For more details, see this page about lifecycle hooks:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: You still need to have a `playlist` property on the class or this won't compile

Comment: You're right. I was focused on when displaying the property, so I forgot the property declaration. I updated my answer. Thanks!